# partitions in hive interview questions

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hiveql, mapper, hive-partitions

1) If the partitioned column doesn't have data, so when you query on that, what error will you get?

2)If some rows doesn't have the partitioned column , the how those rows will be handled? will there be any data loss?

3)Why bucketing needs to be done with numeric column? Can we use string column also? what is the process and on what basis you will choose the bucketing column?

4) Will the internal table details will also be stored in the metastore? Or only external table details will be stored?

5) What type of queries, that runs only at mapper side not in reducer and vice versa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answers:

**1.** if the partitioned column doesn't have data, so **when u query on that**, what error will you get?

Partitioned column in Hive is a folder named `key=value` with data files inside. And if it has no data, it means no partitions folders exist and the table is empty, no error displayed, no data returned.
When you inserting null in partitioned column using dynamic partitioning all NULL values within the partitioning column (and all values which do not conform to the field type) loaded as `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` If the column type is numeric in this case then the type cast error will be thrown during select. Something like cannot cast textWritable to IntWritable for example

**2.**  if some rows doesn't have the partitioned column , the how those rows will be handled? will there be any data loss?

If "does not have" means NULLs, then loaded as **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION** Actually it is still possible to get data, no loss happened

**3.** Why bucketing needs to be done with numeric column? **-it does not need to be numeric** can we use string column also? **Yes.** what is the process and on what basis you will choose the bucketing column.?

Columns for bucketing should be chosen based on joins/filter columns. Values are being hashed, distributed and sorted(clustered) and the same hashes are being written (during insert overwrite) in the same buckets(files). The number of buckets and columns are specified in the table DDL.

Bucketed table and bucket-map-join is a bit outdated concept, you can achieve the same using DISTRIBUTE BY + sort + ORC. This approach is more flexible.

**4.** will the internal table details will also be stored in the metastore? or only external table details will be stored?

Does not matter external or managed. Table schema/grants/statistics is stored in the metastore.

**5.** what type of queries ,that runs only at mapper side not in reducer and vice versa?

Queries without aggregations, map-joins(when small table fits in memory), simple columns transformations (simple column UDFs like regexp_replace, split, substr, trim, concat, etc), filters in WHERE, sort by - can be executed on mapper.

Aggregations and analytics, common joins, order by, distribute by, UDAFs are executed on mapper+reducer.

> runs only at mapper side not in reducer and vice versa

vice versa is not possible. Mapper is used to read data files, reducer is the next optional step which can not exist without mapper, though map->reduce->reduce... is possible when running on Tez execution engine. Tez can represent complex query as a single DAG and run as a single job and remove unnecessary steps used in MR engine such as writng of intermediate results into hdfs and reading again using mapper. Even in MR map-only jobs are possible.

Comment: thank you so much for the answers. one more, internal table will be stored in /usr/hive/warehouse. but the external tables are not persistent.or will it be stored any where?

Comment: @Anonymous Only TEMPORARY tables are not persistent. Data for both EXTERNAL and MANAGED are in the distributed filesystem. Metadata - in the metastore. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242477/2700344

Comment: @Anonymous And of course read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038932/2700344 - tests with explanation

Comment: so you mean to say that , when managed table is created, it will be stored in  /user/hive/warehouse/database_name.db/managed_table_name . And when external table is created, then it will also  be stored in the same locations /user/hive/warehouse/database_name_external.db/external_table_name.

Comment: @Anonymous At least this happens in my cluster. I'm not sure if some configuration for default external table location separately exists.

Comment: Basic idea is that EXTERNAL table is intended to be managed by some side tools, not Hive. This is why the data is not being deleted when drop table issued. That's it

Comment: ok, thank you once again. Sorry for asking all these type of questions. As am new to it. am getting all these doubts

Comment: one more question please, how to get the tables that are locked at rdbms side using sqoop import. this is also one of the interview question?

Comment: @Anonymous Ask this as a question, someone else might able to answer. I do not know all answers. Something like https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowLocks

Comment: @leftjoin-- A great explanation. Is distribute by and sort by with orc hive tables works better than Hive Bucketed tables?  I think below question is also referring to same queries.. Could you please also explain this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722268/sorted-table-in-hive-orc-file-format Thanks

Comment: @vikrantrana Answered. buckets are files. creating files dynamically depending on the data size is better (using distribute by in the query + bytes per reducer.)